# Mysql and ppoll

Tags: mysql, asynchronous

As far as I see, by `mysql_get_socket_fd`, one can get the filedescriptor of a mysql connection. If I use this filedescriptor in `select`/`ppoll`, will the subsequent mysql command succeed without blocking? That is, will it only have one write- or read-syscall?

**Update:** Ok, what I actually want to know is, is it possible to use mysql asynchronously with a ppoll-loop?

Answer (score 1):

Most unlikely. SQL transmissions can be arbitrarily large, and the amount of data transferred in non-blocking mode is finite, limited by the size of your socket send or receive buffer.

Comment: Ok. So there is no alternative to using it synchroneously in an own thread?

Comment: I didn't say that, but if your definition of success is a single read or write, you need to revise it.